# check or reading sms from inbox in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sms

I need to implement a small text ui to show sms message from inbox in unity.
After searching, I only find how to use Application.OpenURL to send a sms message.

Does anyone know how to check or sms message in unity without opening default sms app?
My test environment is Nexus 6p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a plugin for that. You write 2 functions that can read and write to messages in Java then call those functions from C#. You can also use this [plugin](https://gist.github.com/taesiri/7431660) from this nice person on the internet.

Comment: Could you give me more detail how to do that ? Do I need to compile those  java files? Or I just simply put those files into the Assets/Plugins/Android??

Comment: Yes, if you are using eclipse, you compile the plugin to .jar and place the .jar file to Assets/Plugins/Android. If you are using Android Studio, compile the Java file to .arr then place it anywhere in your project file and it will work. You can google how to do this. Once you understand it it you can compile the java code from the plugin link I posted above.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.