# Reading SMS from inbox in Unity Android and iOS deployment

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, one-time-password

I need to implement a small text UI to show OTP MSM messages from inbox in Unity.

Does anyone know how to check or send SMS messages in Unity without opening the default SMS app?

I found the link below for sending the message without launching default SMS app. I want to read the SMS message in order to auto fill the OTP for the registration process. Is it possible with Unity?

https://gist.github.com/rmdwirizki/87f9e68c7ef6ef809a777eb25f12c3b2

[check or reading sms from inbox in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364305/check-or-reading-sms-from-inbox-in-unity)

https://gist.github.com/taesiri/7431660

Comment: On Android platform, I believe it can be done with writing your own plugin with Java. [Building and using plug-ins for Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) I am willing to create a simple demo project to show how to do that. But it might takes some time.

Comment: On iOS you cannot read the user's messages.  It would be a privacy violation.  In iOS 12 if you set a text field type to "password" then iOS will suggest an incoming OTP as an autofill option if one is detected.

Comment: Thank you @ming060. I will try to develop using the "Building and using plug-ins for Android" and i will let u know if time permits show me some sample or guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android platform:

**Demo Project** [here](https://github.com/ming060/UnitySMSReceiver)

1. Create an [AAR plug-ins and Android Libraries](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html). (You can either chose jar or aar to implement the plugin, the only difference is that aar plugin contains Android resources. In this case, we need to add permission into AndroidManifiest.xml which can be put inside aar and be merge by Unity automatically later)

   Follow this instruction [Create an Android library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#aar-contents).

   In the aar plugin, implement a `BroadcastReceiver` that handles SMS receive intent.

   SmsListener.java

   ```
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

   import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

   public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
       private final String UnityCallbackObject = "UnitySMSReceiver";
       private final String UnityCallbackMethod = "OnSMSReceive";

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

           Object[] objects = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
           SmsMessage message = null;
           for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
               message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objects[i]);
               builder.append(message.getDisplayMessageBody());
           }
           UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UnityCallbackObject, UnityCallbackMethod, builder.toString());
       }
   }
   ```

   AndroidManifiest.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="your.package.name.here">

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

       <application>
           <receiver android:name="your.package.name.here.SmsListener" android:enabled="true">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
2. In Unity side, put the generated aar file into `Assets/Plugins/Android`.
   Create an gameObject named `UnitySMSReceiver` and attached a script implement function `OnSMSReceive` in the scene.

   ```
   public void OnSMSReceive (string message) {
       // do something with your SMS message here.
   }
   ```

   My Environments:

   ```
   Unity 2017.2.0f3

   Android Studio 3.2.1
   ```

References:

[Android testing sms from emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638252/android-testing-sms-from-emulator)

[Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

[How can I read SMS messages programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675729/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-programmatically-in-android)

[Android: Programmatically receiving SMS messags](http://droidcoders.blogspot.com/2011/09/sms-receive.html)

[Android SMS Receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339654/android-sms-receiver-not-working)

[Unity3D and aar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803490/unity3d-and-aar-issue)

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

Comment: Thank you so much @ming060 its working great. I tried to create a new project based on your instruction, It is working good. Thanks.

Comment: But i have one doubt, it is receiving all the sms content. How can i restrict the particular sender sms should receive. I had control the content and got the OTP number alone in the unity side.

Comment: How do you pass the message content from Android side to Unity side now?

Comment: I am not passing msg from android to unity. Exactly my need is when user register application with the email and mobile number. We are try to verify the mobile number using the OTP method. Basically here we are sending msg to the concern number through the bulk sms portal from backend. I had trip the string based on my need. and try to display. Thats what i am asking can we read the particular sender sms.

Comment: So, are you using an Android plugin to retrieve all SMS messages on the phone?

Comment: Yes but not all msg. For example : "your Mi Account verification code is 068887. This OTP expires in 1 days". From this sms I need to read that OTP alone to auto fill. Need to read the sms from particular recipients.

Comment: Do you only want to get the "068887" code from the message?

Comment: Yes @ming060 absolutely.

Comment: If your OTP SMS message satisfies certain pattern, use `Regular expression` to filter the OTP code is the first way I think of.

Comment: Sure i will try that way. But my concern is to retrieve msg from the particular sender not all msg. We usually get OTP msg from the bank sites also or other login or forget pwd method.

Comment: In my above demo project, I can get the sender of the SMS message. I don't know  whether you can get that info from your plugin.

Comment: I will check @ming060.

Comment: @keerthikaitmit Were you successful in retrieving msg from the particular sender? If so can you please help me with the same?

Comment: is this still working? can't find a way to make it receive an sms

Comment: Hi @Skin_phil, just fixed the problem. And please make sure to grant SMS permission manually.

Comment: Thank you, yeah the problem was actually getting the permissions, after that no problems